# How to add data inside two arrays inside for loop

Tags: arrays, swift, for-loop, google-cloud-firestore, swiftui

I'm trying to add data to array inside for loop and again to array in another for loop.
Its working on first for loo, but in second data is empty. How to fix that

This is how it currently looks inside firestore and you can see scores missing.
[image: How it looks inside firestore]

this is code:

```
func updateCourseData() {

    var data = ["endTime": Timestamp(date: Date()),
                "players": []] as [String : Any]

    for i in 0..<players.count {

      var playerData = ["playerId": games[i].id,
                        "scores": []] as [String : Any]

      var existingItems = data["players"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]()

      existingItems.append(playerData)

      data["players"] = existingItems

      for score in 0..<selectedPage + 1 {

        let scoreData = ["hole": games[i].scores[score].hole,
                         "score": games[i].scores[score].score] as [String : Any]

        var existingScores = playerData["scores"] as? [[String: Any]] ?? [[String: Any]]()

        existingScores.append(scoreData)

        playerData["scores"] = existingScores
      }
    }

    Constants.FirebaseCollection.gamesCollection.document(documentId).updateData(data) { error in
            if let error = error {
              print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
            print("Game updated")
          }
}
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to do, since both existingItems and existingScores are declared inside a `for` loop they will only exists for one iteration of the loop so once the loops are exited nothing will remain. So your code really doesn't do anything.

Comment: Added firebase part from code. It push data to firestore

Comment: Ok, now I understand your code better. The main problem is that you are doing things in the wrong order, you need to first update the scores so that when you append playerData to existingItems it should already contain the scores.